# Find a basis of $U=\{ p \in \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{F}) \ | \ \int_{-1}^{1} p = 0 \}$

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Find a basis of $U=\{ p \in \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{F}) \ | \ \int_{-1}^{1} p = 0 \}$.

My method behind showing my list of vectors spans the space seemed a bit odd, so I was hoping if I could get a second pair of eyes to glance over things.

**Attempt:**

Let's let $p(x) \in U$ be arbitrary. Note then then that $p$ is of the form
$$p(x)=a_4x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0.$$
Further, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} \sum_{i=0}^4a_ix^i = 0 &\implies \sum_{i=0}^4 \frac{a_i}{i+1}x^{i+1} \Bigg|_{-1}^{1} = 0 \\
&\implies \frac{2a_4}{5}+\frac{2a_2}{3}+2a_0=0. & \qquad (*)
\end{align*}
Thus it's clear that $a_1,a_3$ can take on any value, hence $x,x^3 \in U$. If we solve $(*)$ for $a_0$, we see that $x^4+x^2-\frac{16}{30}\in U$. And if we set $a_0=0$, we also obtain that $-\frac{3}{5}x^4+x^2 \in U$.

We now show the obtained list of vectors is linearly independent. Take $a_1, \dots, a_4 \in \mathbb{F}$. Then from
$$a_1x+a_2x^3+a_3 \left( x^4+x^2-\frac{16}{30}\right)+a_4 \left( -\frac{3}{5}x^4+x^2 \right)=0$$
we have
$$a_1x+(a_3+a_4)x^2+a_2x^3+(a_3-\frac{3}{5}a_4)x^4=0$$
therefore
$$\begin{cases} a_1=0 \\ a_3+a_4=0 \\ a_2=0 \\ a_3-\frac{3}{5}a_4=0 \end{cases}$$
which shows that $a_1=\cdots=a_4=0$, so the list is linearly independent.

Therefore we know that $\dim U \geq 4$. By a previous theorem, we must have $\dim U \leq \dim \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{F})=5$. But by one of the previous exercises, for a subspace $U$ of $V$, if $\dim U = \dim V$ then $U=V$, and here we have $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{F})$ but $\frac{1}{2} \not \in U$, so this cannot be the case. Thus $\dim U=4$ and the list of vectors must span the space.

Comment: It seems unnecessary, the initial space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}^5$ and your computation gives one nontrivial homogeneous linear equation, so the dimension of the space is $4$ (if you like this follows from the rank-nullity theorem). As for building a basis, you can iterate through the free variables, setting each free variable equal to $1$ while setting all the others equal to zero, and solve the linear equation for the "pivot" variable.

Comment: @Ian I haven't visited that theorem yet -- but I do have a question, if $U \cong \mathbb{F}^5$, wouldn't $\dim U = \dim \mathbb{F}^5$? So am I wrong about the dimension here? (Also, goes without saying that I can't quite see how they're isomorphic...) Also, I'm not sure I've ever seen that method for building a basis, I'll look more into it!

Comment: I mean the initial space $\mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{F})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}^5$: you constructed one such isomorphism already in your question in mapping $(a_0,\dots,a_4)$ to polynomials and vice versa. Imposing one nontrivial linear equation on $\mathbb{F}^5$ results in a 4-dimensional subspace.

Comment: I don't think I understand the argument about nontrivial linear equations. I take it you're referring to the mentioning of coeffecients having to satisfy $(*)$, if so, how exactly does that imply this is a 4-dimensional subspace?

Comment: The direct argument is by constructing a basis in the manner I said: if you have, say, $a_0=-a_2/3-a_4/5$, then you can construct a basis by iterating through $i=1,2,3,4$ and setting $a_i=1$ and all other $a_j=0$, and obtaining a corresponding value of $a_0$. So one basis is $x,x^2-1/3,x^3,x^4-1/5$.

Comment: @Ian Ahhh everything you said makes sense now. So given $(*)$ and using your method, perhaps having written it as $a_0=-\frac{2}{10}a_4-\frac{2}{6}a_2$, I would've obtained a basis of $x,x^2-\frac{2}{6},x^3, x^4-\frac{2}{10}$, right? This is really efficient, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Your basis is actually exactly the same as mine, you just didn't reduce the fractions. But $a_0$ being the pivot variable wasn't essential. If you wrote the equation in the form $a_2=-3a_0-3a_4/5$, running the procedure would give a basis of $1-3x^2,x,x^3,x^4-(3/5)x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to do this problem is to use the isomorphism between $\mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{F})$ and $\mathbb{F}^5$, which you already constructed. Then the condition reads $2a_0+2a_2/3+2a_4/5=0$ in $\mathbb{F}^5$, as you computed. To construct a basis for the solution space to this homogeneous linear "system" (of one equation), rearrange it to have one of the three variables on one side and the others on the other side. The first variable will be your single pivot variable, and the other four variables are free.

The "standard recipe" for constructing a basis is then to set each free variable equal to $1$ and all others equal to $0$ and obtain a corresponding value of the pivot variable(s). This bypasses this awkward argument about dimensions, which would be much more annoying to write if you had, say, two independent linear equations. This choice of $1$s and $0$s is not essential, any sequence of vectors which can be assembled into an invertible matrix would suffice. The identity matrix is just a nice simple choice.

Then to get a basis back in the original space, just use the isomorphism to go back.